# Muti-column ordered list in C#

Tags: c#, html-lists, indentation, multiple-columns

If I have a list of roughly 303 employee names. The names are in order and I would like to display them in the same order vertically as a minimum of two columns. I'd like to take it a step further by listing the items as an ordered list indenting If there are an odd number of employee names I'd like it to create the addtional column as is needed.

Sample data: {#HR,Jim, Kelly, Micheal, #OPS, Janet, Karen, Mary, #IA, Jorge, Katie, #Budget, Sarah, Alex, Roger, Sam, #ESD, Tom, Fred, Jarold}

I would like for this information to be displayed as a two or more columned ordered list with indentation for fields that do not begin with #. I hope I've clearly conveyed what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Column A    | Column B   | Column C   |
-----------------------------------------

-#HR        | -#IA       | -#ESD 
  -Jim      |    -Jorge  |    -Tom
  -Kelly    |    -Katie  |    -Fred
  -Micheal  | -#Budget   |    -Jarold
-#OPS       |    -Sarah  |
  -Janet    |    -Alex   |
  -Karen    |    -Roger  |
  -Mary     |    -Sam    |
------------------------------------------
Column A    | Column B   | Column C   |
```

Here is the code that I came up with so far. I get horizontal results instead of vertical results.

```
    writer.Write("<center><table border='0'>");

    for (int j = 0; j < staffList.Count; j++)
    {
        if ((j % 5) == 0)
        {
            //Create initial table row and column
            writer.Write("<tr><td><li>" + staffList[j].ToString() + "</li></td>");
        }
        else
        {
            //create the rest of table rows and columns
            writer.Write("<tr><td><li>" + staffList[j].ToString() + "</li></td>");
        }
    }
    writer.Write("</ul></tr>");
    writer.Write("</table></center>");

    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: @ZAD-Man, I've included what I was able to come up with in the post. It's not pretty.

Comment: Thanks. No need for it to be pretty, it's more to show that you've put in more effort than just asking us what to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.aspx) web element. You can use its `DataBind()` method to associate it with a collection, which you can then use to store your table of data.

For indentation, off the top of my head, one simple way might just be something like

```
foreach(string v in MyCollection){
    if (v[0] != '#' && v[0] != "&")
        v = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + v;
}
```

For every string in the table, that does not begin with '#' or already have whitespace, prepend some space.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a generic table then piggy back off a built-in class to get the indentation i wanted.